# Using ALIAS and Max() in Doctrine Query

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to use MAX and CASE in DQL:

```
SELECT u, 
  s, 
  st, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN s.schedulesTypeId = 2 THEN s.createdAt END) AS start 
FROM ApplicationBundle:Schedule s 
JOIN s.users u 
JOIN s.scheduleType st
```

But when I run the code

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 73: Error: Unexpected ')'
```

Without the MAX() and AS (alias) the code runs perfectly, but I need to add this MAX() to complete my Query.

What can be the problem? I'm using Symfony 2.6

Thank you.

Comment: I am not expert of dql but try to add `ELSE NULL` before `END` in your case

Comment: I had to add `ELSE 0` instead `NULL`, but is the same.

Comment: Now I have this: `MAX(CASE WHEN st.id = 1 THEN s.createdAt ELSE 0 END) s.start` and this error: `Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_FROM, got '.'` how to add `start` in `s` alias association?

Comment: `ApplicationBundle:Schedule` is it normal for dql? for tsql and most sql servers it must be `ApplicationBundle.Schedule` with point `.` not colon`:`

Answer (score 0):

> MAX(CASE WHEN s.schedulesTypeId = 2 THEN s.createdAt END) AS start

This could not work. Put "1" at the end of the word "start" and it will work..

This is because start could not be used in dql... but i did not find a way to manage this ...